# What is the protestant's view on cybersex?

Tags: protestantism

I just wanted to ask this to clarify if the Catholic and Protestant Churches have different views regarding this matter. Thank you. :)

Comment: There isn't really such a thing as "the Protestant church", I'm afraid.

Comment: There are too many types of Protestants out there. Anyone who rebels against or protest against the Roman Catholic Church during the Reformation era, and their biological or spiritual descendants, can be labelled "Protestants", really.

Comment: You're probably going to have to define 'cybersex' a little more closely as well.

Comment: This question has the same flawed assumption as described in [Is it valid to ask if “Christianity” teaches anything?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2237/is-it-valid-to-ask-if-christianity-teaches-anything)  Put simply, there is no one "Protestant Church" and the opinions are myriad (although you'd find pretty consistent teachings on this)  You might find useful information on this post: [Clarification of what sexual immorality is?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11299/clarification-of-what-sexual-immorality-is), which covers the basic principles applied.

Answer (score 10):

Does Ccybersex involve *thinking* of having sex with someone when looking at her? If so, these words of Jesus apply:

**Matthew 5:27-28**

> You have heard that it was said to those of old, "You shall not commit
>   adultery."
>
> But I say to you that whoever looks at a woman to lust for her has
>   already committed adultery with her in his heart.

Comment: I think this would basically be the standard Protestant answer.