# how does the bible WORD FOR WORD say that homosexuality is wrong?

Tags: history

I'm just really curious and trying to put down some speculations my friends and I have.

Comment: The different Christian branches have different positions about this. Would you like to ask about a specific one? You could ask about Evangelical Protestants, Anglicans, Roman Catholicsm, Eastern Orthodox...

Comment: can you give me the thoughts from all branches?

Comment: The Bible condemns it in [Leviticus 18:22](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=leviticus%2018:22), [Leviticus 20:13](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=leviticus%2020:13), [1 Corinthians 6:9-10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20corinthians%206:9-10), and [Romans 1:26-28](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%201:26-28).  But, of course, there is debate.  Read [other questions about homosexuality](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/search?q=homosexuality), and if you have any more specific questions that haven't been asked yet, feel free to ask.

Comment: but does it WORD FOR WORD (as said in my question) say that homosexuality is a sin?

Comment: if all it says is "it should be man and woman" then you can not count that as valid proof that it condemns it. keyword-should. but does not say it has to be.

Comment: I didn't read the word "should" in any of the four passages I linked to in my comment.  If you are looking for a literal, word-for-word condemnation of homosexuality, I don't know how those four passages could be any more clear.  However, I'm not really looking for a debate.  Check out [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/121/what-does-the-bible-say-about-homosexuality), which has much more detailed answers to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here  are some references for homosexuality and treating it to be against the nature of God and his design. There are though some translation variations, but whatever translation one take they portray basically same point.

**1 Corinthians 6:9**

> Or do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived: neither the sexually immoral, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor men who practice homosexuality,(ESV)
>
> Do you not know that wrongdoers will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived! Fornicators, idolaters, adulterers, male prostitutes, sodomites,(NRSV)
>
> Or do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived; neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor [a]effeminate, nor homosexuals(NASB)

**1 Timothy 1:10**

> the sexually immoral, men who practice homosexuality, enslavers, liars, perjurers, and whatever else is contrary to sound doctrine,(ESV)
>
> fornicators, sodomites, slave traders, liars, perjurers, and whatever else is contrary to the sound teaching (NRSV)
>
> and immoral men and homosexuals and kidnappers and liars and perjurers, and whatever else is contrary to sound teaching,(NASB)

**Romans 1:26-27**

> For this reason God gave them up to dishonorable passions. For their women exchanged natural relations for those that are contrary to nature;and the men likewise gave up natural relations with women and were consumed with passion for one another, men committing shameless acts with men and receiving in themselves the due penalty for their error.(ESV)
>
> For this reason God gave them up to degrading passions. Their women exchanged natural intercourse for unnatural,and in the same way also the men, giving up natural intercourse with women, were consumed with passion for one another. Men committed shameless acts with men and received in their own persons the due penalty for their error.(NRSV)
>
> For this reason God gave them over to degrading passions; for their women exchanged the natural function for that which is [a]unnatural, and in the same way also the men abandoned the natural function of the woman and burned in their desire toward one another, men with men committing indecent acts and receiving in [b]their own persons the due penalty of their error(NASB)

**Jude 1:7**

> just as Sodom and Gomorrah and the surrounding cities, which likewise indulged in sexual immorality and pursued unnatural desire, serve as an example by undergoing a punishment of eternal fire.(ESV)
>
> Likewise, Sodom and Gomorrah and the surrounding cities, which, in the same manner as they, indulged in sexual immorality and pursued unnatural lust, serve as an example by undergoing a punishment of eternal fire.(NRSV)
>
> just as Sodom and Gomorrah and the cities around them, since they in the same way as these indulged in gross immorality and went after [a]strange flesh, are exhibited as an[b]example in undergoing the punishment of eternal fire.(NASB)

Homosexuality is definitely against the nature and contrary to God’s design. Even when there is a loud clamour for justification of homosexuality in a liberal world (where good is projected as bad and vice versa)  on the basis emotional factor involved between these individuals, they fail to justify the very physical act of homosexuality minus this emotional factor. Emotionally they may feel attracted towards one another yet physically they cannot accommodate one another and that itself is the testimony that it is an emotional sickness/disorder which needs to be corrected.

And in that sense these people cannot be treated as outcasts but like any other disabled person needing corrective treatment.

Comment: "And in that sense these people cannot be treated as outcasts but like any other disabled person needing corrective treatment." Or like any other sinner who needs to confess and repent their sin, who can then be welcomed and accepted by the church. :)